# In which folder in R should the 3dplot.sty file be saved?

Tags: r, latex, r-exams

I am creating a question in `r-exams` that contains a graph made in `TikZ`, more specifically https://texample.net/tikz/examples/the-3dplot-package/. For its correct operation it is required that the `3dplot.sty` file be in a certain `R` folder. In which folder should I include this file?

Error message in `RStudio`: "!LaTeX Error: File`3dplot.sty'not found".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly recommend to install this in the `texmf` tree of your LaTeX installation. Then it is always found, no matter where you compile a LaTeX file.

Alternatively, you can also specify it using the `header` argument in `include_tikz()` with the full absolute file path:

```
include_tikz(..., header = "\\usepackage{/full/path/to/3dplot}")
```

Note that the `.sty` suffix is not to be included, even when using the full file path.

Comment: Very effective, as always. Thank you.

Comment: Is it not recommended to use the \ begin {axis} and \ end {axis} environment? Many other exercises work fine for me, except for those with {axis} ... (! LaTeX Error: Environment axis undefined).

Answer (score 1):

If you only need it for one project, simply place the `.sty` file in the same folder as your .rmd file. The current working folder is the normally the first place latex searches for packages, before looking in your personal texmf folder or your tex distribution.

Comment: This works for regular Rmd files that are compiled in the place where they are stored. But this does not work for Rmd exercises from R/exams because these are copied to a temporary directory and then compiled there (possibly numerous times).